# Tweepy Python Compare two lists with IDs

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file as an initial list and a textfile with gathered Twitter IDs using Tweepy. Now I want to delete all IDs in the textfile which are not in the csv file.
I created some code but I think there is a problem with the split since I am only getting back an empty textfile.
The list I want to filter has the format: Name,ID,[222286905, 314205957, 2216185789, 102454880, 3376328482,...]

```
import csv

id_set = set()
with open("C:/PATH/twitter_ids.csv") as file1:
    r = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=";")
    for l in r:
        id_set.add(l[2].strip())

with open("all.txt", "r") as file2:
    confirmed = []
    for l in file2:
        l = l.strip()
        if l in id_set:
            confirmed.append(l.split("[",", "))
with open("all.txt", "w") as file2:
    file2.write("\n".join(confirmed))
```

Comment: What output you are getting right now?

Comment: empty textfile. I think every single ID in the square brakcets needs to be checked separetly if it is in the CSV list, maybe thats the problem but I dont kn0w how to solve it

Comment: Are the IDs the same type (string, integer, etc.) between the two files? Rather, when you put the elements in the set, are they still of type string?

Comment: no in the csv file it is: name;job title;ID;party

Comment: No, I mean in your comparison `if l in id_set`, if `l` is a string `123` and `id_set` contains the integer `123`, the condition is false. Is it possible that you have a type mismatch like this?

Comment: ah, yes maybe. What would be the right way than?

Comment: but this shouldnt be a problem in python right?

Comment: This would definitely be a problem in Python. Try `'123' == 123`. This should return False. You can check the type of an object by `type(obj)`. You could print out `print(type(l))` in your for loops to verify. If they are the same type, then there's something else going on. Also, could you post what `confirmed` and `id_set` look like?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a small sample of lines from both of your input files and also what you would expect as output from the sample.